# Extension of a holomorphic curve in $B^4$ to one in $\mathbb{C}P^2$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, sg.symplectic-geometry, pseudo-holomorphic-curves

Let $B^4$ be the closed unit ball in $\mathbb{C}^2$ and $J$ an almost complex structure sufficiently closed to the standard complex structure on $\mathbb{C}^2$ in the $C^0$-topology. Let $u \colon S \rightarrow B^4$ be a smooth $J$-holomorphic curve transverse to $\partial B^4$. Can $u$ extend to a $\tilde{J}$-holomorphic curve in $\mathbb{C}P^2$? Here $\tilde{J}$ is an extension of $J$ on $\mathbb{C}P^2$.

Any hint and comment are really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can extend $u$ to a symplectic surface $C$ in $\mathbb{CP}^2$ so that it's non-singular outside of $B^4$. Once you do that, I think you can find a compatible $\tilde{J}$ that extends $J$ and for which $C$ is $J$-holomorphic.

Comment: How do you extend it to a global symplectic surface? (And then yes, obstruction theory lets you extend $J$ to $\tilde J$.)

Comment: Thanks, Marco and Chris. I agree that you can extend $J$ to $\tilde{J}$ in a manifold containing $B^4$. I am not so sure if one can close off the boundary of $C=u(S)$ in $\mathbb{CP}^2$. I guess that it depends on the (transverse) isotopy class of the boundary link $\partial C$ in $\partial B^4$. What if $C$ is sufficiently close in some sense to a (genuine) complex curve in $B^4$ with a unique singularity at the origin?

Comment: (continue) In this case, the complex curve $C'$ has a cap in $\mathbb{CP}^2 \setminus B^4$ coming from a canonical exteinsion of $C'$ in $\mathbb{CP}^2$. I think that after perturbation this cap can be used to make $C$ a closed symplectic surface in $\mathbb{CP}^2$. What do you think?

Comment: John Etnyre and I have shown that you can always cap off a transverse knot in $S^3$ with a symplectic surface in $\mathbb{CP}^2\setminus B^4$. (arXiv:2001.08978)

Comment: Thank you so much, Marco for letting me know your paper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

The "boundary" $\partial B \cap {\rm Im}(u)$ of $u$ is a link $K$ that is transverse to the contact structure $JTS^3\cap TS^3$, which is isotopic to the standard contact structure on $S^3$. John Etnyre and I [proved](http://arXiv.org/abs/2001.08978) that every transverse link in $(S^3,\xi_{st})$ can be capped off by a smooth symplectic surface $\hat C$ in $\mathbb{CP}^2\setminus B^4$ (here $B^4$ is a Darboux ball). We call any such cap a *hat* (because "relative symplectic cap" was too long).

As Chris Gerig mentions in his comment above, you can extend $J$ to an almost complex structure $\tilde J$ on $\mathbb{CP}^2$ for which $C = \hat C \cup u(S)$ is pseudo-holomorphic.

The argument of the proof of the existence of $\hat C$ isn't very hard: one constructs a cobordism to a torus link using local moves on braids, and then caps it off with a piece of an algebraic curve.